# django application works on development server but I get 404 on Apache

Tags: django

I thought the very same mechanism would work both for development server and Apache as my web server but I am currently really confused.

I can access a URL whilst using the Django development server as follows

```
__http://devserver/my_application/
```

When I switch my web server to Apache, I am getting Django 404 errors for all URLs.py entries.

trying to access __http://devserver/ returns the following

```
Using the URLconf defined in antrum.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^my_application/$
^my_application/?page=(?P<page>\d+)
^my_application/new
^my_application/(?P<candidate_id>\d+)/$
^my_application/(?P<candidate_id>\d+)/update/$
^my_application/(?P<candidate_id>\d+)/delete/$
^my_application/search/$
^admin/doc/
^admin/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

Trying to access http://devserver/my_application/ results the following output

```
{'path': u'my_application/'}
```

I am probably making a lame mistake but can not get to see that now. What might have I been missing to check?

Here's my Apache configuration

```
<Location "/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE project.settings
    PythonOption django.root /
    PythonDebug On
    PythonPath "['/home/user/','/home/user/project/'] + sys.path"
</Location>

<Location "/media/">
    SetHandler None
</Location>
```

Here are my findings:

- Switching to manage.py runserver solves my problem
- Apache Error.log has no entries
- When I set the Environment variable for pythonpath and use the python CLI, I can access my models, which also IMHO leaves the python path option off of this
- __http://devserver/my_application and __http://devserver/my_appTYPO gives the same error message with different {u'path': ...} output

Comment: error.log seems clean >> [Thu Jan 06 19:48:52 2011] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp 
[Thu Jan 06 19:48:52 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.6.6 configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: access.log seems clean as well, I see my GET requests

Comment: this completely happens at django level. I am suspecting of urls.py or my pythonpath. no luck so far...

Comment: I doubt this is happening at the Django level, since it works fine with the dev server. What does your Apache configuration look like?

Comment: "Switching to manage.py runserver solves my problem"  What?  You can't run this in production.  So how is it a "solution"?  Please be very specific on why you think this "solves" you problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set django.root variable when mounting at the root of the web site. That should only be used where mounting at a sub URL.

Answer (score 1):

try to use mod_wsgi instead of modpython. if you have the same issues then revise your views especially HttpResponse object (mimetype argument) . anyway modpython will no longer supported after django 1.3 release, i think it's better idea to leave modpython forever

Comment: I will go for mod_wsgi on my production environment. thanks for the reminder